# Simulation of sampling frequencies, but for one particular frequency the code "breaks", maybe np.sin approximation errors?

Tags: python, numpy, sampling, python-dataclasses

I am simulating a signal with numpy.sin in python, and i wanna simulate different sampling frequencies, the code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequencies = [10, 20, 40, 49, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 301, 526, 1222] # different sampling frequencies
T = 1 #amount of time for which to simulate the signal in seconds
f = 50 #frequency of the signal

for i in frequencies:
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
    N = T * i # number of samples needed at the sampling frequency for the elapsed time of the signal
    linear = np.linspace(0, T, N) # create the data points at which to evaluate the sin 
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * linear) # evaluate the sin for the amount of sample points
    #creat the graph
    ax1.scatter(linear, y) 
    ax1.set(ylabel = 'Amplitude', xlabel = 'Time in s')
    fig.savefig('Freq{}.png'.format(i))
    plt.close(fig)
```

The problem arises with the sampling frequency 101, here the sin function evaluates to ridiculously tiny values, something around 10^(-14) (for all the other values normal graphs come out)
([Sin function Evaluated with a sampling frequency of 101 Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXByr.png))
whilst if I evaluate the sine func by hand by printing out the linear array for sampling frequency 101 Hz, I get normal values.
Does somebody know the problem? Maybe and approximation problem of np.sin? maybe the dtype float64 somehow breaks, because the values are kinda sus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `i` is 101, `f * linear` is `[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, ...]`, so the expression `np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * linear)` is sampling the `sin` function at multiples of `pi`.  If you were working with infinite precision, the values would all be 0.  These sample points, however, will not be *exact* multiples of `pi`, because of normal floating point imprecision, so the values returned by that expression should be close to 0, but they won't necessarily be exactly 0.

Comment: OMFG, i tohught i was going insane. but absolutely true. jesus. But thanks for the answer, i guess ill just fix the axis limits to +1 -1 to highlight that they are "basically" 0